# Creating Base for non-flat surface

Tags: modeling

Can You tell me how to create a base for 3d scanned sculpture (with some surrounding - roots, rocks etc.) where such thing like "flat surface" does not exist (please take a look at attached pic).

[image]

Model has it's texture and I would like to preserve it :) Maybe it would be nice to apply texture or color for base. 
Can You tell me how to achieve effect similar like this? (not my model unfortunately, just a random screenshot).

[image]

I'll be very, very, very grateful for help.

Thanks in advance!
Konrad

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to select the outer edges and extrude them downwards to get a base that you can then detail and fill, for something circular after extruding use `Shift Alt S` then `1` to force a circular shape as in your second image.

Answer (score 3):

If your model has nice geometry around the edges, the first step should be a lot easier.
My answer is provided as [an Imgur post (for some reason the steps are in a funny order, sorry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1WpY.jpg) as I can't upload the gifs here - they're too big. I'll outline the basic steps though, just in case the link dies for any reason. All of the operations are performed in Edit mode.

Step 1: Select the vertices around the base of the mesh.
Step 2: Extrude the vertices down to whatever you want the depth to be along the z axis (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>MOUSEMOVE</kbd>). Then flatten them to a plane (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>).
Step 3: Make a face by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>. You may want to recalculate normals at this point.

Comment: To add video as gif and has to be smaller than 2mb. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056#1056 and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/522/placing-gifs-in-text

Comment: Thanks Guys! Hmmm... Geometry of the model is nice but far away from being simple :) It has thousands of vertices on the edges. Do I have to extrude all of them one by one? Is there any easier way? Sorry for such silly question but I am begginer in the subject. BTW. Is there a way to create from i.e. cube some kind of a thub which can be used to embrace the model, edges and create as a boundary? Thanks!

Comment: As you can see in my gif, try using Alt+Shift+RMB on the vertices, which (if you're lucky) will select multiple vertices at once. Don't extrude them one by one, or you'll have to rejoin them - extrude only when they are all selected.

Comment: @cegaton I know, that's why they're not in the question but separately hosted on imgur.

Comment: @Konrad, with bounding it to a cube, first use Recalculate Normals on the mesh with all vertices selected (after you've given it a base). Then use a Boolean modifier on the mesh you want to bound to the cube, which (I think) should be set to Intersection, and then set the other object to the cube you want to bound it to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select all vertices manually. As ChiCubed's video shows, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>. But there's an even faster way:

- [Select non-manifold edges](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#mesh-select-non-manifold) - Ctrl+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Now, you could extrude in place:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to split the edges off from the main mesh
- Optionally:

  - Press <kbd>P</kbd> to make a new mesh (if you want to use some modifiers later like solidify, this may help)
  - switch to editing the new mesh
- <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> and drag down to extend the base down
- Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>`0`</kbd> to make the base flat

Comment: Ok, I'll try both ways. I just need to wait few days because there are other stuff to do offline :) For sure I'll let You know what was the result!

Have a nice sunday!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome again!

At first - BIG THANKS!! Extruding the edges works :) It was pain on the back side (since model does not have the smooth geometry as I said, I had to mark multiple edges almost endlessly) but finally I'm there! :) Now I need to finish it.

I started with this:

[image]

Now it looks much better :)
[image]

Complex geometry of the edges resulted in striped, camouflaged almost appearance of the base. Is there a way to make them flat ant smooth + adding the i.e. dark grey color to differentiate sides and base from the model?

And two more:

1) How to export the model together with textures? Where can I find the option to export whole set of files (obj, mtl plus textures) to be able to view the model properly in whatever editor/viewer I need?

2) what can I do to reduce size of the model? simple scaling it (I guess) will not solve the problem because model is still complex. Smoothing it is the way I should follow or is there any other method to make it loose some megabytes?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Konrad,
Maybe consider opening a new question for each of those questions, I'll gladly answer them! However, I will quickly address some of your questions. For the camouflage, select the edge and the extruded edge at the base, and go to the Materials tab, make a new diffuse material, and click 'Apply' while *only* the edge and the base are selected. For question 1), I think there's an option to export as obj + mtl and this should include textures provided they are in the same folder. For question 2), you may want to look at some retopology tools.

Comment: Also @Konrad, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it :D